# mysql query for the following problem?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables say 'user', 'user_resources' and 'desktop_resources'.

'user' contains - emp_id,name and other attributes 
'user_resources' - emp_id and desktop_id foreign key relation
'desktop_resources' - desktop_id and other attributes

Now i want a sql query from where i can get a table which shows me name from 'user' table and 'desktop_resources' attributes only where "emp_id=d_id"

how to go about it??

Comment: What did you try? You have almost arrived at the query. It is not difficult. give it a shot. Try...

Comment: seriously why the down vote..stackoverflow should start implementing a system where a reason has to be given for the downvote..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found this query useful:

```
SELECT name, desktop.*
FROM desktop
NATURAL JOIN (
user
JOIN user_resource ON user.emp_id = user_resource.emp_id
)
```

I am sure there may be other ambiguous queries for this..if u have got a better query..please put it in comments...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see d_id column there, but if you think so, it would look like this:

```
SELECT name, desktop_resources.*
FROM desktop JOIN user_resources USING (desktop_id) JOIN user USING (emp_id)
```

Comment: actually the emp_id and d_id are in the user_resources table...its the foreign key association table for user and desktop_resources table(emp_id is in user table and d_id is in desktop_resources table).

Comment: this is the query i finally settled on... SELECT name, desktop.*
    FROM desktop
    NATURAL JOIN (
    user
    JOIN user_resource ON user.emp_id = user_resource.emp_id
    )

Comment: will put it in answer later(cant do it so early yet... ;( )

Comment: @user597272: nice! I would however not recommend to use NATURAL JOIN. Use USING instead: ... FROM desktop JOIN user_resources USING (desktop_id) JOIN user USING (emp_id).

Comment: editted answer to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

This is a straightforward series of joins:

```
select u.name, dr.*
from user u
join user_resources ur on ur.emp_id = u.emp_id
join desktop_resources dr on dr.desktop_id = ur.desktop_id
where u.emp_id = $d_id
```